# Changing exisiting standard property to DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is that possible to change for example MediaElement.Position property to DependencyProperty by inheriting MediaElement class and then creating DependencyProperty in a new class from inherited class?

How to do it? AFAIK DependencyProperty stops normal behaviour of default accessor, how to reconnect things to not break up after change?

I want to update Slider.Value through Binding thus I need MediaElement.Position as DependencyProperty. I know I can do it with DispatcherTimer but I think it's not professional solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create either a custom control (a XAML-less control that inherits from MediaElement) or a UserControl with a MediaElement somewhere in its visual tree.

In either case, create your DependencyProperty, and use the PropertyChangedCallBack (in FrameworkPropertyMetadata) to respond to changes made, and use events to listen the other way.

In either case, you are creating a new control to use instead of the MediaElement. The advantage of a User Control is that you only expose the properties needed. The disadvantage being naturally that you have to expose them all. The custom control will also expose the Position property even though you don't want to use it.